# Handlebars:How do i access array by value?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

I have a simple array 'names' with name and id.
I'd like to access the name from other loop (phones).
Code is below:

```
{{#names}}
      {{name}} - {{id}} // this shows for example '123456 -  001'

{{/names}}

{{#phones}}
    {{number}} - {{id}}
    -->here i'd like to fetch a 'name' from names based on phone {{id}}

{{/phones}}
```

Is there something like `{{../names.id['001']}}`??

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing something like this:

```
{{#phones}}
    {{#../names}}
        {{#ifeq ../id this.id}}
            {{this.name}}
        {{/ifeq}}
    {{/../names}}
{{/phones}}
```

with ifeq being this helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function (a, b, options) {
      if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); }
    });
```